How to config IP Access List Entries to access mongodb atlas service in render
I make a site using MERN & frontend has already deployed in Netlify.
Then I has deployed my backend code in render.com
To confirm the service work correctly, I test with postman & discover following errors.
Do simple CURD with Postman to deployed project in render.com

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I work at Render.
Our documentation offers a list of static outgoing IP addresses that you can configure at Mongo Atlas for access control.
https://docs.render.com/static-outbound-ip-addresses
